"startElmishLoop" fails in Elmish.wpf with Elmish v4.2
Having upgraded to Elmish v4.2, I now find that Elmish.wpf v4.0.0-beta-44 crashes on startup with
WpfProgram.mkProgram init update bindings
 |> WpfProgram.withLogger (new SerilogLoggerFactory(logger))
 |> WpfProgram.startElmishLoop mainWindow 

where WpfProgram.startElmishLoop stops with the below error. Is Elmish.wpf compatible with Elmish 4.2 ?? (if so, what is the correct call?)
Thanks for any help :)
Addendum: This question should probably be deleted. The simple answer is upgrade Elmish.wpf. After paying more attention to the output warnings on compile:
" Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Elmish.WPF 4.0.0-beta-44 requires Elmish (>= 3.1.0 && <= 3.99.0) but version Elmish 4.2.0 was resolved."
All problems were resolved when Elmish.wpf-4.0.0-beta-55 was installed. :)
System.MissingMethodException
HResult=0x80131513
Message=Method not found: 'Elmish.Program4<System.__Canon,!!2,System.__Canon,!!3> Elmish.ProgramModule.withSyncDispatch(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc2<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc2<System.__Canon,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc2<System.__Canon,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>>, Elmish.Program4<System.__Canon,!!2,System.__Canon,!!3>)'. Source=Elmish.WPF StackTrace: at Elmish.WPF.WpfProgram.startElmishLoop[model,msg](FrameworkElement element, WpfProgram2 program)
at Stargate.XI.Client.MainWindowModule.main(FrameworkElement mainWindow) in C:\Stargate.XI\Stargate.XI.Client 0.0.6\Stargate.XI.Client\Stargate.XI.Client\MainWindow.fs:line 123
at Stargate.XI.Client.Views.App.StartElmish(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Stargate.XI\Stargate.XI.Client 0.0.6\Stargate.XI.Client\Stargate.XI.Client.Views\App.xaml.cs:line 28
at System.Windows.Application.OnActivated(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Application.WmActivateApp(Int32 wParam)
at System.Windows.Application.AppFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)

Update elmish.wpf. (Read output errors!)
